# Magento 2.3 can't upload product images

Tags: magento2, product-images, forms, file-upload

Every time I try to upload product images on my Magento 2.3 website, I get the following error:

**A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.**

The same problem occurred when trying to upload our logo. I had found an article online telling me to change 2 form elements set to "file uploader". When changing this to "image uploader" it fixed the logo problem. I'm assuming this product image problem is occurring for the same reason the logo one was happening. In which file should I change this?

Answer (score 0):

please check your folder media has permission write.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your file permissions? If you checked them, and you are 100% certain that it should work, did you check SELinux?

Answer (score 0):

A commit has been published in the magento 2.3 develop branch to address this issue, and can be found here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/ba69bfec127bed8c39c7d9e7b73d10b54449b158

It may be worth trying a similar change in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml for product images.

Answer (score 0):

There are ton of issues could be the cause,

You better ask someone can check the log and permanent fix this