# which is the compatible xampp version of this magento Magento-CE-2.3.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, xampp

which is the compatible xampp version of this magento version Magento-CE-2.3.1-2019-03-18-06-24-49 (1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one with [**PHP version 7.2.11**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.2.11/) as Magento 2.3.1 is certified and tested on this according to the [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#php).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't full compatible. You will have problems such as these

[Can't upload product images on Magento 2 Xampp](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257085/cant-upload-product-images-on-magento-2-xampp)

[Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder)